# How do i install a library in MacOS Clion

Tags: c, macos, libraries, clion

Im a new CS student and my professor wants us to use a specific [library](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/) for making basic graphics in C. I'm quite new with macOS and especially with CLion and i was wondering if any of you guys could help me install it. Even tho there's a CMakeList file in the selected library, i couldn't integrate it with the IDE. However, compiling from the console works ( a bit uncomfortable ).

Comment: If the library is intended to be installed system-wide, it should come with an installer.

Comment: it doesnt have any